# How to display char in grid lines using c#

Tags: c#

I am working on a desktop application develop in C#. what i want to do is to:

Open a text file(.txt) Read Data Line By Line Create a grid type structure(i.e combination of
 horizontal and vertical line) Then take first line and display its each char in single cell And the take second line and display its each char in single cell and so on.

Since i am beginner so i don't have any idea that how to acheive this. I only want some suggestions and guidance.

Comment: Is it a web application or Winfroms

Comment: @ Dorababu its a desktop application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is actually easy to do provided you compose the correct items together to get your result.

You'll want to look up [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) operations, [string manipulation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (as well as the knowledge that a string is nothing but an [enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65zzykke.aspx) of chars), and then some simple [looping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) to get what you want.

At a high level, you'll just be needing to get the math right to display your set of text as a grid in X columns by Y rows.

Answer (score 1):

Use File.ReadAllLines(). It will give you and array of strings - line by line.

For each string returned by ReadAllLines use string.ToCharArray. It will give you an array of symbols in string.

**Update:**

Number of columns in grid will be equal to max length of char array. Number of rows - to number of lines. Hope, I understood your task correctly.

Comment: Yes you understand right, but how can i display the grid lines on screen?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a homework problem?

Use the [File class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3saad2h5.aspx) to read your text file. As far as printing the output to the screen, you have many options...if you're building a console application the you could just write characters to the output using the [Console methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz3fhfz1.aspx).

Hint: to split each line of text into characters, use the `ToCharArray()` method on the [String class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can read from a text file line by line

```
    int counter = 0;
    string line;

    // Read the file and display it line by line.
    System.IO.StreamReader file = 
       new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
    while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
       Console.WriteLine (line);
       counter++;
    }

file.Close();

// Suspend the screen.
Console.ReadLine();
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287535(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287535%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)